# Nativescript charts not displaying

Tags: nativescript

I am a newbie to Nativescript and currently working on a Nativescript project using javascript. I am exploring the charts option and have installed the nativescript UI charts using the 'tns plugin add nativescript-ui-chart' command. When I try to display a simple line chart I do not get any errors, but nothing gets displayed as well.

**Here is my XML file:**

```
<Page class="page coverImage" navigatingTo="onNavigatingTo" xmlns="http://schemas.nativescript.org/tns.xsd" xmlns:chart="nativescript-ui-chart">
<Label text="Test Charts Page"></Label>
<StackLayout>    
<Label text="Test"></Label>
     <chart:RadCartesianChart class="m-t-10" height="500">
      <chart:RadCartesianChart.series>
        <chart:LineSeries
          items="{{ animeData }}"
          categoryProperty="season"
          valueProperty="count">
          <chart:LineSeries.horizontalAxis>
            <chart:CategoricalAxis labelFitMode="Rotate" />
          </chart:LineSeries.horizontalAxis>
          <chart:LineSeries.verticalAxis>
            <chart:LinearAxis labelLayoutMode="Outer" />
          </chart:LineSeries.verticalAxis>
        </chart:LineSeries>
      </chart:RadCartesianChart.series>
    </chart:RadCartesianChart>
  </StackLayout>
</Page>
```

**My javascript file:**

```
   var frameModule = require("ui/frame");
var Observable = require("data/observable").Observable;  
var pageData = new Observable();
pageData.animeData = [
 { season: "1", count: 82 }, { season: "2", count: 36 }, { season: "3", count: 41 },
 { season: "4", count: 52 }, { season: "5", count: 65 }, { season: "6", count: 40 },
 { season: "7", count: 52 }, { season: "8", count: 54 }, { season: "9", count: 47 },
 { season: "10", count: 52 }, { season: "11", count: 52 }, { season: "12", count: 53 },
 { season: "13", count: 34 }, { season: "14", count: 48 }, { season: "15", count: 49 },
 { season: "16", count: 45 }, { season: "17", count: 48 }, { season: "18", count: 45 },
 { season: "19", count: 47 }
];
exports.pageLoaded = function(args) 
{
     var page = args.object;
     page.bindingContext = pageData;
};
```

I have added the nativescript-ui-chart to bundle.config as follows:

```
global.registerModule("nativescript-ui-chart",
        () => require("../node_modules/nativescript-ui-chart"))
```

**Package.json:**

```
   {
  "description": "NativeScript Application",
  "license": "SEE LICENSE IN <your-license-filename>",
  "readme": "NativeScript Application",
  "repository": "<fill-your-repository-here>",
  "nativescript": {
    "id": "org.nativescript.pregapp4",
    "tns-ios": {
      "version": "4.0.1"
    }
  },
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint \"app/**/*.js\""
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "nativescript-theme-core": "~1.0.4",
    "nativescript-ui-chart": "^3.9.1",
    "nativescript-ui-dataform": "^3.7.3",
    "nativescript-ui-listview": "^3.7.2",
    "nativescript-ui-sidedrawer": "^4.3.1",
    "tns-core-modules": "^5.0.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "eslint": "~4.9.0",
    "nativescript-dev-sass": "~1.5.0",
    "nativescript-dev-webpack": "~0.10.0",
    "webpack": "~3.10.0",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^2.9.1",
    "webpack-sources": "~1.1.0",
    "clean-webpack-plugin": "~0.1.19",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "~4.3.0",
    "raw-loader": "~0.5.1",
    "css-loader": "~0.28.7",
    "nativescript-worker-loader": "~0.8.1",
    "resolve-url-loader": "~2.2.1",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "~3.0.2",
    "uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "~1.1.6",
    "sass-loader": "~6.0.6"
  }
}
```

On running this I donot get an errors, but just a blank white space - not sure what I am missing - any help will be appreciated..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like data model is not getting set to Observable. I have changed the code to following in it's working fine for me on ios.

```
var observableModule = require("tns-core-modules/data/observable");

function HomeViewModel() {
  var viewModel = observableModule.fromObject({
    animeData: [
      { season: "1", count: 82 }, { season: "2", count: 36 }, { season: "3", count: 41 },
      { season: "4", count: 52 }, { season: "5", count: 65 }, { season: "6", count: 40 },
      { season: "7", count: 52 }, { season: "8", count: 54 }, { season: "9", count: 47 },
      { season: "10", count: 52 }, { season: "11", count: 52 }, { season: "12", count: 53 },
      { season: "13", count: 34 }, { season: "14", count: 48 }, { season: "15", count: 49 },
      { season: "16", count: 45 }, { season: "17", count: 48 }, { season: "18", count: 45 },
      { season: "19", count: 47 }
    ],


  });

  return viewModel;
}

module.exports = HomeViewModel;
```

Here is the playground [link](https://play.nativescript.org/?template=play-js&id=kHhJnf), in case you want to add something to this.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your plugin path needs to be fixed

```
<Page class="page coverImage" navigatingTo="onNavigatingTo" xmlns="http://schemas.nativescript.org/tns.xsd" xmlns:chart="nativescript ui-chart">
```

suppose to be

```
<Page class="page coverImage" navigatingTo="onNavigatingTo" xmlns="http://schemas.nativescript.org/tns.xsd" xmlns:chart="nativescript-ui-chart">
```

Comment: I did have it as nativescript-ui-chart in the code, that does not seem to be the prblem.

Comment: Please make sure you post exact sample code, possibly a Playground example.